# About in parsing with python after using get function of request module

Tags: html, parsing, web-scraping, web-crawler

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://kind.krx.co.kr/disclosure/todaydisclosure.do?method=searchTodayDisclosureMain&marketType=0'
krx = rq.get(url)

krx_html = BeautifulSoup(krx.content, 'html.parser')

krx_title = krx_html.select('section.wrapper-contents > section.contents')

print(krx_title)
```

I executed this code.
Please look at the picture below
Obviously, 'article' tag have many tail tag in html element.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nii8u.png)

But the result of the executed code does not have the tail tag, only the code below:

```
<article class="pcontents" id="main-contents">
</article>
```

why come up this problem?
Did the developer block it?

Comment: `requests` cannot process javascript.  Most modern webpages depend on javascript.